# Why is the rating tab in VLC not working?

Tags: vlc

I can't assign ratings! What is the rating tab for? It has always been blank and doesn't change.

Edit: Sorry for omitting the details. Please don't criticize my choice of music.

can't do anything to the ratings, for any kind of media file.
[image]

proof that I'm using Ubuntu -- apparently, my coming to this forum is not sufficient to infer this.
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to rate mp3?

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you running? Did you use Software Center to install VLC? Can you include a screenshot in the question?

Comment: I'll be second to ask that. I am trying to rate OGG and I don't see how to do this with stock VLC on 14.04 LTS.